# How to prevent multiple updates in a record in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page, in which the users can create/open a project and view/update its information. The information is stored in a MySQL database. The users can share their own projects with their partner, so that their partner can edit their projects too. In this case if two or more users open a particular project at the same time, they can overwrite the updates of each other. Therefore I need to develop a reliable code to prevent such concurrent updates and give the users appropriate message. Is there any pattern or best practice for addressing such  case? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

A simplistic approach would be to put a sequence number on each record that is incremented when the record is changed.  When the page loads you would include the sequence number as a hidden `<input/>` and send this with your update query:

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 = '?', field2 = '?', sequence = sequence + 1
WHERE id = ? AND sequence = ?;
```

After running the query you can see how many rows were modified (your database API should provide a way to retrieve the number of "affected rows" following a query).  If zero, then either the record ID was not found, or the record was modified by another user (the `sequence = ?` clause did not match).

Comment: Better to track the sequence number as a session variable, on the server side (lest a malicious user attempt to circumvent it).

Comment: @eggyal The impact of altering the sequence variable doesn't seem high.  If they choose anything but the right value, the edit will be rejected due to a perceived concurrent edit.  If they choose the right value then it has the same effect as going to a fresh edit page and inputting all of the same values.  I'm not saying putting it in the session is a bad idea, but I don't think it's necessary either.  (Plus, that would complicate things dramatically if the user has multiple edit pages open at the same time!)

Comment: @eggyal Although it is required, but it doesn't address the following issues: 1- It lets the last user, who opens the project form, to update the form. However in my case, the first user should be the one who still is able to update. 2- During the editing and before clicking the Submit button, it doesn't give the user any heads-up that the form is not going to be saved . Hence they might be annoyed when they find that all their efforts won't be saved. Does it make sense? It there any other way that we can address the above issues?

Comment: @Fred Of course.  Simply detect that no rows were modified, and then present the exact same form to them again, with their previous entries pre-populated, along with an informative error message stating what happened.  Include all of the information in the updated record, so that the user is able to see what has changed and merge anything as necessary.